# CDK pipelines accessing assets in stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk

I'm using the new `pipelines` module in aws-cdk to build a multi account code-pipeline deploying a spring boot application to beanstalk.
I followed this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/) and implemented my own subclass of `Cdk.Stage`.
This stage class creates a new backend stack:

```js
export class BackendStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, artifact: Artifact, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const image = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'backend-image', {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'backend'),
            buildArgs: {
                'JAR_FILE': './target/app.jar'
            },

        })

        const dockerRunFile = {
            "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "ContainerPort": 8080,
                    "HostPort": 8080
                }
            ],
            "Image": {
                "Name": image.imageUri
            }

        }
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'Dockerrun.aws.json'), JSON.stringify(dockerRunFile));

        const versionAsset = new Asset(this, 'version-asset', {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'Dockerrun.aws.json')
        })

        const appVersionProps = new CfnApplicationVersion(this, 'backend-app-version', {
            applicationName: appName,
            sourceBundle: {
                s3Bucket: versionAsset.bucket.bucketName,
                s3Key: versionAsset.s3ObjectKey
            }

        });
    }
...
}
```

Unfortunately the image.imageUri resolves to `Token[TOKEN.219]` and not the correct image URI.
I think this has to do with the resolution of Cloudformation tokens.
In my opinion I have to delay the creation of the `Dockerrun.aws.json` but I don't know how to achieve that.

Is there any other way to pass assets like the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file to the backend stack ?
I need it to deploy the beanstalk application correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out correctly, the resolution of tokens happens inside CloudFormation, so you cannot write it to a file. Is there a way to not use a real file but to provide the sourceBundle inline in CFN? Then CDK would generate a correct GetAtt inside your template to reference the uploaded file.

But please make sure you activated the newStyle synth so it might work when it uses hard-coded strings instead of parameters then. You need the new bootstrapping for this.

Be aware that all this is not GA yet.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by inlining the sourceBundle ?
I can either pass : `CfnApplicationVersion.SourceBundleProperty | cdk.IResolvable` to the sourceBundle property ?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to put the Code inline instead of pointing to S3, but that is not possible according to the docs. You should definitely try out the new synthesizer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `imageUri`, you can build the image URL like this:

```
const account = Stack.of(this).account;
const region = Stack.of(this).region;
const imageName = `${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${image.repository.repositoryName}:${image.imageTag}`;
```

Make sure you permit Elastic Beanstalk to access the ECR commands:

```
role.addManagedPolicy(
  ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
    'AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess',
  ),
);
```